# Core 2.0 Publish IIS HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, publish, kestrel

I have read a lot of post with the same error I have. The problem I have is that  I have it running on the same machine I developed the solution.

I have Windows 8.1 and IIS 7.5. Express I am running several MVC Framework XXX solutions on me IIS and I do not have problems. The problems appears when I publish a solution Core 2.0...

I have created a basic Web Core 2.0 MVC solution. Just the same project it is created by Default. (Created an Core 2.0 MVC and Publish it).

I have Visual Studio 2017, so I have installed SDK installed.

I have created a site in IIS (inetpub/wwwroot) for it, drop in the published code, and configure the App Pool to run "No Managed Code". I set port to 5010.

When I run the Project from cmd: `dotnet core20.dll` it says it is running listening on port 5000, instead on port 5010.

So, i set port 5000, but when i run it from cmd it shows an error.

```
Microsft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0] Unable to bind to localhost:5000 on the IPv4 loopback interface: Error 4092 EACCES permission denied. Unabled to start Kestrel.
```

Why it runs on port 5000 if I set on port 5010?

When I run it from Browser i have this error

[image]

My web.Config is the basic web.config created ruting the publishing..

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\core20.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 21dc60b6-a958-447d-8ed3-25a6195a06ea-->
```

`On Windows Features turn on or off--> IIS Services--> Application Development Features`, all options are selected

The error I have

I have the same problem with `Core 2.0 Angular` Application... So I miss to install something.

I have not installed `the .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle`. I do not know it is necessary.

I do not know if i have to install `Kestrel`, or how to install it.

I asume all this has to be installed when I installed Visual Studio 2017.

Any ideas what I am missing?

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I have not installed the .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle. I do not know it is necessary.

There's your problem. Install the hosting bundle. Without it, IIS has no idea how to handle an ASP.NET Core app. In particular, your error here is because the `<aspNetCore>` tag doesn't exist for usage by Web.config, without that bundle either. So, while the error is a bit obtuse, it is technically telling you what the issue is.

Additionally, after installing the bundle, you must either restart your server or completely stop and restart the IIS service (*not* `iisreset`):

```
> net stop was /y
> net start w3svc
```

It's better to restart the server entirely, if you can, just to make sure everything is fresh, but starting and stopping web services should be enough to load in the ASP.NET Core module.

All of this is covered in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?tabs=aspnetcore2x#install-the-net-core-windows-server-hosting-bundle).